# Html table: columns that fill content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table that has different column-widths depending on the content, i.e:

```
content | a longer text that is cut of ... | a longer text that is cut of ... | content
```

The content will be different, so the solution cannot be hard coded for the different cols.

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? How wide should a column be? How should the final result looks like? Please edit your question and add all relevant details so as to make a [mre].

Comment: You need to provide some code you have tried, or at least a starting point. Right now you have only describe what you want other people to write for you without showing anything at all.